# number of solutions to an equation for $x,y \in R$ where $R$ has infinitely many units

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, unique-factorization-domains

"Let $R$ be a ring of complex numbers. Assume $R$ is a UFD and has only finitely many units.Let $k$ be a non-zero element of $R$ Prove that;

$$x^2 - y^2 = k$$

Has only finitely many solutions with $x,y \in R$. Can the said be the same if we have infinitely many units?"

My first attempt was to split this equation up into 2 factors;

$$(x+y)(x-y)=k,$$

and then using the fact that R is a UFD to show that k has a unique factorization that we can exploit to find simultaneous equations in $x$ and $y$, but couldn't quite get the answer I wanted. I'm wondering what units have to do with it and how to use them to prove the statement?

Comment: In a UFD, factorizations are only unique up to units. Thus you can have several factorizations of $k$. But if you know that there are only finitely many units, then there should be only finitely many factorizations.